# Adding Substring in table loop in Html.DisplayFor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Im just asking how to implement Substring code in Razor Html DisplayFor

Actually It was working before then I added the Substring to get the first 5 number in the table then I encountered an error

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Here are my set of Codes:

```
<tbody>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Cards.Count; ++i)
             {
                var counter = i + 1;
                <tr>    
                    <td valign="middle"> 
                        <p class="small">@counter</p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle">
                        <p class="small">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Cards[i].Number.Substring(0,5))</p>
                    </td>
               </tr>
             }
</tbody>
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: You cannot use methods (i.e. .`Substring()` in an expression. What `[DisplayFormat]` do you have on the `Number` property?

Comment: And the fact you have `.Substring()` does not really make sense if its a number (unless the number is a `string`, and then the property name does not make sense). If it as a `string`, then all you need is `<p class="small">@Model.Cards[i].Number.Substring(0,5)</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stephen said in comments, using `.Substring` in the middle of your view doesn't really make sens.

Instead, in your ViewModel (the one which defines your `Number` property), add the following property :

```
public string DisplayableNumber => Number.Length > 5 ? Number.ToString().Substring(0, 5) : "WhatYouWantHere";
```

This will work for C# 5+, else you can use the old way and initialize it in the default constructor.

Then, use it in your view :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Cards[i].DisplayableNumber)
```

Plus, this is good practice to use this type of property in ViewModel, as Views should't handle any logic.